# Apache camel, upload a files to folder in the S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am trying to upload the files to a folder under the s3 bucket but I am getting the error as below :

Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Pradeep

```
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: null (Service: S3, Status Code: 403, Request ID: xxxxxxxx, Extended Request ID: xxxxxxxxx)
```

my code upload the files as follows :

```
 String awsRegion = "eu-west-1";
 String bucketName = "webdavs3bucket/myfolder";
 String s3Endpoint = "aws2-s3://" + bucketName + "?region=" + awsRegion + "&useDefaultCredentialsProvider=true";


from("file:{{base.working.dir}}")
                .log("Uploading file latest changes====>: ${header.CamelFileName}")
                .log(s3Endpoint)
                .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, simple("${file:name}"))
                .toD(s3Endpoint)
                .log("File uploaded successfully to S3");
```

Comment: Welcome Pradeep. There is plenty of information online on Stack Overflow and other places regarding 403 errors in S3. Unless we have more detailed information regarding your error (including your stack trace), we can't help you sadly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got the issue, it is because of the policy which was restricting the user to upload files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).